# What are the relations between the tracer, tracee and calling processes in strace with -D and without -D?

Tags: strace

I have some difficulty understanding the -D option of strace. strace manpage says

> -D          Run tracer process as a detached grandchild, not as
>                      parent of the tracee.  This reduces the visible effect of
>                      strace by keeping the tracee a direct child of the
>                      calling process.

Is "tracer process" the process which runs strace?

Is "calling process" the parent process of the "tracer process"?

What are the parent-child relations between the tracer, tracee and calling processes, without -D  and with -D?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tracer process is the process which runs `strace`, yes. The calling process is the process which starts `strace`, so typically your shell.

Without `-D`, the traced process’ parent ends up being `strace`:

```
strace sleep 120
```

shows up in `pstree` as

```
-───zsh───strace───sleep
```

With `-D`, `strace` detaches itself and ends up being re-parented, on my system to my user `systemd` process:

```
    |-systemd-+-(sd-pam)
   ...
    |         |-gnome-terminal--+-3*[zsh]
    |         |                 |-zsh---sleep
   ...
    |         |-strace
```

The impact of the `-D` option is briefly described in [the `strace` man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html#DIAGNOSTICS):

> Note that parent-child
>          relationship (signal stop notifications, `getppid()` value, etc)
>          between traced process and its parent are not preserved unless `-D` is
>          used.

Running with `-D` means that the child will find its expected parent when it calls `getppid()`, and it also makes `SIGCHLD` behave correctly when the child is stopped and continued. This can be important in circumstances where you insert `strace` between a process and its children, when its children need to find their parent.